# Windows too large on netbook

Tags: 12.04, window, aspire-one

I am running ubuntu 12.04 desktop on an Acer Aspire One D255 netbook. Certain windows are too tall for the screen. For example save windows will have the "save" button off the bottom of the screen. This problem does not happen with the 2D desktop. Does anyone have a fix? Or is there a way to change the default size of such windows?

Answer (score 3):

Some windows, like save dialog boxes and even worse, some preferences windows have a fixed size determined by the program so there is no universal setting.

There is a workaround. Although it not a very nice solution, you could move the window by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag the window to show the hidden part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Switching the dialog window to **fullscreen** helps in most cases. It's still annoying to do so every time, though.